# kotlin recyclerview MVVM error - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

On recyclerview I'm setting a list, using MVVM where I'm getting an error,
IndexOutOfBoundsException.
code I use for recyclerview adapter is below - onBindViewHolder is where I set articles:List

```
  class MainAdapter(private val context: Context,private val articles:List<Article>) : ListAdapter<Article, MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>(DiffUtil()) {

    inner class MainViewHolder(val binding: HomeRecViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {

        val binding = HomeRecViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MainViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val articles_ = articles[position]
        holder.binding.artical = articles_

    }

    class DiffUtil : androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
}
```

my ViewModel is given below

```
  val article : LiveData<NewsModel>
    get() = repoHelper.article
```

my main Activity

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var article_: List<Article>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_test)

        article_ = ArrayList()
        val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this,article_)
        binding.recView.apply {
            this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@TestActivity)
            this.adapter = mainAdapter
        }

        val apiHelper = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(ApiHelper::class.java)
        val database_ = DBHelper.getDatabase(applicationContext)
        val repoHelper = RepoHelper(apiHelper,database_,applicationContext)

        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelFactory(repoHelper)).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        mainViewModel.article.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d("list_of_article",it.articles.toString())
            mainAdapter.submitList(it.articles)
        })
    }
```

what's the main cause for this error and how do I resolve it.

Comment: Can you please add the Exception log (stacktrace) and maybe some more code of your Adapter?

Comment: yes - edit adapter class

Comment: `override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }` is not added in the adapter class. Try after adding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
article_ = ArrayList()
val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this,article_)
```

Here you provide an empty list to the Adapter.

After this never changes!

`mainAdapter.submitList(it.articles)` does not set this list in the adapter.

So `val articles_ = articles[position]` will try to access something from an empty list.

As a matter of fact. You don't even need to have this list at all. ListAdapter has methods to access the list you provide with `submitList`

Instead of

```
val articles_ = articles[position]
```

you can do

```
val articles_ = getItem(position)
```

and then you can remove the articles completely there so change

```
class MainAdapter(private val context: Context,private val articles:List<Article>)
```

to

```
class MainAdapter(private val context: Context)
```

and change

```
val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this,article_)
```

to

```
val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this)
```

Comment: Yes i resolved it by change val articles_ = articles[position] to val articles_ = this.getItem(position)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

You are not implementing the `getItemCount()`. It returns the size of the list.

```
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }
```

**Cause** of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is that you are trying to access the index of list which is beyond the size of list.

### Example:

The size of list is 2. So the elements will be at index 0 and 1. If you try to access index 2 then you will get to see `IndexOutOfBoundsException`